# Running Tomcat from NetBeans

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, netbeans6.5

I have installed Apache Tomcat and then I installed NetBeans. Then I added the Tomcat instance to NetBeans servers. Whe I try to run the server from NetBeans, something goes wrong.. Server starts and is running, but NetBeans does not know that and waits for the server to start forever (until a unsuccesfull message is displayed).

I tried NetBeans 6.5.1 and 7M1 and Tomcats 5.5 and 6 with same results :/

I was using NetBeans with Tomcat before with no probleams..so I think it is not a bug, but only some wrong configuration.

Any clues?

Comment: Finally solved it by deleting NetBeans profile (.netbeans folder) and reinstalling NetBeans with Tomcat bundled (custom installation)

Comment: I suggest you to add the above comment as answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem with netbeans 6.9.1. I downloaded the latest nightly build which fixed the issue and now I'm able to use an unbundled version of tomcat. There is a bug report here with more info:
[netbeans bugreport](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=160392)